# How to find $\sum_{l=2}^{100} \frac{1} {\log_{l} 100! }$

Tags: sequences-and-series, logarithms

I am trying some question in sequence and series of an institute in which I don't study and I was unable to solve this particular question .

> Question: Find the sum :$\sum_{l=2}^{100} \frac{1} {\log_{l} 100!}$ .

A 0.01

B 0.1

C 1

D 10

I am sorry but I would not be able to provide an attempt on this because I am absolutely clueless On how to aproach this even though I am good in Logarithms and sequence and series.

Comment: $\frac{1} {log_{l} 100!}=\log_{100!}l$; can you continue now?

Comment: @Conrad +1 : so elegant that it deserves to be an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$S=\sum_{k=2}^{100} \frac{1}{\log_k100!}=\sum_{k=2}^{100} \frac{\log k}{\log 100!}=\frac{\log 2+\log 3+\log 4+\log 5+....+\log 100}{\log100!}$$ $$=\frac{\log (2.3.4....100)}{\log 100!}=\frac{\log 100!}{\log 100!}=1.$$
Option (C) is correct.

Answer (score 4):

$\log_i 100!=\frac{\log_{100!}100!}{\log_{100!}i}=\frac{1}{\log_{100!} i}$. So
$$\sum_{i=2}^{100} \frac{1}{\log_i 100!}=\sum_{i=2}^{100}\log_{100!} i= \log_{100!}\prod_{i=2}^{100} i=\log_{100!} 100!=1.$$

Answer (score 2):

$$\sum_{l=2}^{100} \frac{1} {\log_{l} 100!}=\sum_{l=2}^{100} \log_{100!}{l}=\log_{100!}{2}+\log_{100!}{3}+\log_{100!}{4}+...+\log_{100!}{100}=\log_{100!}({2\times3\times4\times...\times100})=\log_{100!}{100!}=1$$ .